# How to change special XML chars with HTML code?

Tags: regex, oracle11g

I have sentence:

I & my dog went to a walk. We <b>are walking</b> every morning. This is my {<PARAMETER>} and some other special chars <>.

I would like to have some rexep_replace expression to change only special characters that is not a tag or my parameter pattern:

Output would be:

I @amp; my dog went to a walk. We <b>are walking</b> every morning. This is my {<PARAMETER>} and some other special chars @lt;@gt;.

Instead of @ must be &.

I would need SQL or PL/SQL code to do this.

Comment: You wish to HTML encode (but with @ instead of &) any HTML special characters, except those that are inside `{ }` curly brackets?

Comment: And those that are HTML tags.

Comment: Can anynone help me with this?

Comment: This isn't really a case that regex is good at, you need to replace many different instances. Regex may be able to find all those, but you still require a program to choose the proper replacement. Do you have that kind of access?